# Combine Android Platform Styles

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a Honeycomb app that uses fragments and an action bar.  I'd like the action bar to use the Theme.Holo (dark) style but have everything else use Theme.Holo.Light.

I've created an XML file at res/values/themes.xml with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppLight" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
</resources>
```

And then I added this to my manifest's  tag:

```
android:theme="@style/MyAppLight"
```

So basically the whole app is using Theme.Holo.Light now, but so is the action bar, and I need to change that.

What's the best approach for doing this?

Comment: Bonus internets will be awarded if you include working examples or links to them ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the action bar style to your theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppLight" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:Theme.Holo.Dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```